# Configure a parent component using child components like in DevExtreme

Tags: angular

In DevExtreme Angular there are some components that have object properties and collections according to the documentation.

Object Type: https://js.devexpress.com/Angular/Documentation/Guide/Angular_Components/Component_Configuration_Syntax/#Properties_of_the_Object_Type

Collections: https://js.devexpress.com/Angular/Documentation/Guide/Angular_Components/Component_Configuration_Syntax/#Collections

These properties allow you to define some "settings" of the parent component through child components. In other words, instead of passing a configuration as an input property like this:

```html
<dx-data-grid [columns]="myColumns"></dx-data-grid>
<!-- OR -->
<dx-tree-map [tooltip]="myTooltipConfigObject"></dx-tree-map>
```

I can pass it as child elements

```html
<dx-data-grid>
    <dxi-column label="column1"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column label="column2"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column label="column3"></dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>

<!-- OR -->

<dx-tree-map>
    <dxo-tooltip
        [enabled]="true"
        format="thousands">
    </dxo-tooltip>
</dx-tree-map>
```

How could I create a parent component in the same style?

I thought about making a loop through my child components and getting information from them (if a certain child exists, the properties defined, etc.), to apply to the properties of the parent component. But I don't know if that would be the best way.

Comment: I think this is fine way, angular team itself use similar approach, for example in [mat-select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview), they use ContentChildren to iterate through list of options, https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/select/select.ts#L260